# phonegap: Accessing Android Local Images from Hosted Web Application

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

Is it possible that our hosted web application(wrapped inside a Phonegap App) access local files from device data?

something like this:

```
<img src="storage\data\com.phonegap.myapp\img\sample.jpg" />
```

So that when the users open the mobile app, the images will be retrieved from the device storage.

Comment: why not just compile your app with the images you need and put them in a www/images/ folder?

Answer (score 4):

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(imageURI, function(fileEntry) {
fileEntry.file(function(fileObj) {

newimageURI = fileObj.fullPath;
      alert(newimageURI);

});
});
```

I think it will help you